# How to refresh Android app on Locale Change?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, locale

I am working on Android App. The following code is working correctly but when I go to `MainActivity` through `BackPress` button.

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();

        String lang = settings.getString("lang_list", "");
        if (! "".equals(lang) && ! config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
            recreate();
            Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
```

When I change language of my app from `MultiListPreference` It gives an Error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.preference.ListPreference cannot be cast to android.preference.MultiSelectListPreference

And my app crashes..

Please have a look at below code..

```
 final MultiSelectListPreference lang_list= (MultiSelectListPreference) findPreference("lang_list");
            if(news_category_list!=null)
            {
                news_category_list.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
                        AppController.getInstance().notifyPrefrenceChanged(true);
                        //Log.d("on change","change");
                        lang_list.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),getActivity().this));
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
```

How can I refresh the screen with new Language selected. I don't want to go to `MainActivity` after selecting new language. Just refresh the page with current screen when I select another language.

Please help me with this code. **How can I refresh/recreate app (or activity) when I select any language option listed in ListPreference ?**

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know the solution because I'm not really used to Android API, but your error is easy to spot. findPreference is returning a ListPreference and you're casting it to MultiSelectListPreference. Why do you need a MultiSelectListPreference?

Comment: I am giving language options in multilistpreference..

Comment: Well, then you need to change your findPreference method because it doesn't return a multilistpreference (or use the decorator pattern to make a new multilistpreference from a Preference

Answer (score 0):

To go to a specific activity mention the class explicitly:

Replace

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),getActivity().this));
```

with

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), TargetActivity.class));
```

(`TargetActivity` in the line above will be the activity you want to go to)

Comment: I replace this with `MainActivity.class` and it crash the app. by the way my TargetActivity is the current activity. I just want to change language of page when I select another language from `ListPreference`.